# Can not get right value from getlogin() in docker container

Tags: linux, docker, centos7

Newbie for docker , I have a program which I use linux function getlogin() want to be executed  in a docker container

```
    if (geteuid() == 0 && config.multiple_process)
    {
        char *username = getlogin();
```

But ,I cannot get return value from this function when running in a container.
It worked when executed in a centos env directly.

so, what's the difference between them? why i cannot get return value?

env: centos7 gcc 4.8.5

Update:
Add a log to print erorr msg:

```
getlogin failed, detail(6:No such device or address)
```

Comment: Please try to post minimal code that others can simulate your error. This wont help you or others to solve the issue.

Comment: What do you get? Null? `man getlogin` says "getlogin()  returns ... name of the user logged in on the controlling terminal of the process, or a null pointer if this information cannot be determined." It also says  for the null return value: "with errno set to indicate the cause of the error" So try `perror` to get more information. My guess would be that there is no active tty user / controlling terminal  when you run in the container.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram Ok I will give an example later since this code came from my production env .

Comment: @Robert  I add log to print something, I think you are right

Comment: So you take man page and read `ENXIO  The calling process has no controlling terminal`. There is no controling terminal of your process, so getting the name of the user logged to controling terminal is not possible.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes you are right. But I am confused that it works in wmware virtual machine  while it didn't work in docker container